# How to make a webview launch another app in android app

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, webview, android-webview

I am trying to mirror a website in an android app which I already got a way around it, but am having issues with sharing information inside the app to social media, like when it is clicked in the app to share information to WhatsApp, Facebook, etc I want the app to be able to find each app and open the app with the information, I've tried all way but it's not working kindly help if you can
Thanks in advance

my code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView webView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("https://eliteglobalnetwork.net/");
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

    
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (webView.canGoBack()){
            webView.goBack();
        }else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static final String WEBSITE_ADDRESS = "website_address";
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    String url  = getIntent().getStringExtra(WEBSITE_ADDRESS);
    if (url == null || url.isEmpty()) finish();

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_webview); //name of your layout
    WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView.loadUrl(url);
}
```

If want to open in same app -

```
Intent i = new Intent(YourActivity.this, WebViewActivity.class);
i.putExtra(WebViewActivity.WEBSITE_ADDRESS, ""http://www.google.com"");
startActivity(i);
```

Add it in Manifest file -

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```